# How to use one Jquery function to handle multiple onchange (HTML) events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have multiple item name drop-down fields along with price fields. When item is selected corresponding price should be updated in price field.

-----HTML-----

```
<tbody>
        <tr class="d-flex"> 
         <td class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-outline">
            <select  id="selectitem1" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(event)">
                <option selected disabled="True">--- select --- </option>
                 {% for item in showdrop %}
                <option value="{{item.item_price}}" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">{{item.item_name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>  
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-2">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input id="myText1" type="text" class="form-control price" value=" " name="price">
    </div>
    </td>
   </tr>

        <tr class="d-flex"> 
         <td class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="form-outline">
            <select  id="selectitem2" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(event)">
                <option selected disabled="True">--- select --- </option>
                 {% for item in showdrop %}
                <option value="{{item.item_price}}" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">{{item.item_name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>  
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-2">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input id="myText2" type="text" class="form-control price" value=" " name="price">
    </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

---- function-----

```
function myFunction(e) {
        document.getElementById("myText1").value = e.target.value
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to pass a second argument to your function to make it dynamic.

Change the following:

```
<select  id="selectitem1" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(event)">
```

To:

```
<select  id="selectitem1" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(event, 1)">
```

(and repeat for your second select but replace `1` with `2` and so on...)

Then change your function to:

```
function myFunction(e, index) {
    document.getElementById("myText" + index).value = e.target.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` in your function. Based on `this` traverse on DOM find your target and set value.  There are plenty of ways to find desire elements.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  $(e).parents('td').next('td').find('.price').val($(e).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-outline">
          <select id="selectitem1" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <option selected disabled="True">--- select --- </option>

            <option value="1" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">1</option>
            <option value="2" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">2</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="myText1" type="text" class="form-control price" value=" " name="price">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-outline">
          <select id="selectitem2" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <option selected disabled="True">--- select --- </option>
            <option value="3" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">3</option>
            <option value="4" class="form-control" style="color:gray" font-size="20">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="myText2" type="text" class="form-control price" value=" " name="price">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't add the full html code here! Sorry !!! In my scenario a tr contains  4 td's. Itemname,nos,price,amount--- in same order. I tried this code, it didn't work.